# How do dynamically generate this kind of nested li objects using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I want to dynamically generate following kind of nested li objects in my jsp. How Should I do this. I am unable to solve by using simple document.createElement("LI"); and appendElement as I also want to add class to that elements.

```
<li class="level1">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <a href="detail.html#"><img src="images/comments1.gif"
                                    alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <div class="commentlinks">
                                    <a href="detail.html#" class="reply">Reply</a> <a
                                        href="detail.html#" class="like">Like</a> <a
                                        href="detail.html#" class="dislike">Dislike</a>
                                </div>
                                <h5>
                                    <a href="detail.html#" class="colr">By MySebbb:</a>
                                </h5>
                                <p class="time">7 months ago</p>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
                                    adipiscing elit. Sed elit. Nulla sem risus, vestibulum in,
                                    volutpat eget, dapibus ac, lectus. Curabitur dolor sapien.</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Comment: How have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

in JQuery, you can do:

```js
$('<li class="level1"></li>').appendTo('ul');
```

Inside the `li` you can add all your html.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your JS code store the whole html as a string in a variable like `var list = '<li>your code inside list</li>'`. Then use:

```
$('selector').append(list);
```

You can use this statement in a for loop for adding the list multiple times. Hope this is what you were looking for.
Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jagrati16/36t4Lm0a/) example